# Nightwatch Accessing elements inside Perform

Tags: nightwatch.js

we are working with Page objects in nightwatch to check the login functionality of a js page.And using '@'annotation for accessing elements but these elements are not accessible inside a perform function. Below is the code for reference:

```
'use strict';

var paths = require('../../../e2e/paths/paths.js');
var loginData = require('../../../e2e/data/loginData.js');

module.exports = {
url: paths.launchPath,
  elements: {
    username: {
      selector: 'input[name^="username"]'
    },

  },
  commands: [{
    signIn: function() {
      return this
        .waitForElementPresent('@headerTitle', 10000)
        .api.perform(function() {
          var nodeLength = loginData.login.length;
          console.log(nodeLength);
          this.api.waitForElementPresent('input[name^="username"]', 10000)


          for(var i=0; i<nodeLength; i++) {
            console.log('Going for iteration # ' + i  + loginData.login[i].criteria);
            if(loginData.login[i].criteria=='success'){
              console.log('success ' + loginData.login[i].criteria + i);
              this.api.waitForElementPresent('input[name^="username"]', 10000)
              this.api.pause(6000)
              this.api.clearValue('input[name^="username"]')
              this.api.setValue('input[name^="username"]', loginData.login[i].usernam)


            }
            }
          }
        })
    }
  }]
};
```

Can anyone help in accessing these elements inside perform function?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried to use arrow function `.perform(() => { #code})`